# C++ 11 regex: regex error std::regex_constants::error_brack

Tags: c++, regex, exception, c++11

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::regex reg;
  try{
    reg = std::regex(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*");
  }
  catch(std::regex_error &e){
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    std::cout << e.code() << std::endl;
    if (e.code() == std::regex_constants::error_brack)
      std::cerr << "The expression contained mismatched brackets ([ and ]).\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And this gives me :

```
regex_error
4
The expression contained mismatched brackets ([ and ]).
```

What am I doing wrong ? I am using g++ 4.8.2 with `-std=c++11` flag.

**EDIT**
I get the same on ideone http://ideone.com/SDqv0e so it's not the compiler.

Comment: GCC 4.8 has a limited regex implementation. Could you try a different compiler?

Comment: @Biffen I have just updated the question : g++ 4.8.2

Comment: It [seems](http://ideone.com/faq) ideone uses GCC 4.8 too.

Comment: It works on g++ --version 4.9.0, see: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: You're right @CaptainGiraffe . It was the problem with gcc 4.8.2. After installing 4.9.1 it works fine.